# Permuted multiples in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge

How can I improve efficiency/readability of the following code?

> It can be seen that the number, 125874, and its double, 251748, contain exactly the same digits, but in a different order.
> Find the smallest positive integer, x, such that 2x, 3x, 4x, 5x, and 6x, contain the same digits.

https://projecteuler.net/problem=52

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python


def sameDigits(a, b):
    return sorted(str(a)) == sorted(str(b))


def main():
    found = False
    i = 2
    while not found:
        x2 = i * 2
        x3 = i * 3
        x4 = i * 4
        x5 = i * 5
        x6 = i * 6
        if (
            sameDigits(i, x2)
            and sameDigits(i, x3)
            and sameDigits(i, x4)
            and sameDigits(i, x5)
            and sameDigits(i, x6)
        ):
            found = True
            print(i)
        i += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Readablility/pythonization

#### [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is your friend

Use recommended practices, like using snake_case instead of camelCase for functions and variables.

#### Short-circuit evaluation

`and` and `or` operators evaluate the second argument only if the first can't tell the value - like `False` for `and` and `True` for `or`. So, if you move all multiplications in a condition, some of them will not be calculated.

```
if same_digits(i, x*2) and same_digits(i,x*3) and ...
```

#### Move repeating expressions into loops

Luckily, Python has functions to check several expressions for `True` at once: `any` for at least one `True` and `all` for all. They work with a short-circuit and can work with any iterable - like generator expression:

```
if all(same_digits(i, x*j) for j in range(1,7)):
```

#### Generating an infinite loop with itertools.count()

There's a more pythonic way to have something like unlimited range: itertools.count()

```
from itertools import count
for i in count(2):
   #no need to increment i
```

#### Using `break` instead of `found` variable

Though not a structured feature, it can be useful

```
for ...:
    if ...:
        break
```

#### Separate algorithm and input-output

Return the value from the function, not output it. `return` statement works just like break, so we can omit it.

#### All together

```
from itertools import count

def same_digits(a, b):
    return sorted(str(a))==sorted(str(b))

def main():
    for i in count(2):
        if all(same_digits(i, x*j) for j in range(1,7)):
            return i

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(main())
```

### Optimizations

I don't think you can change the complexity of an algorithm, but you can avoid unnecessary actions. Profile the code for everything below - Python is a very high-level programming language, and built-in functions can prove faster then better algorithms for small optimizations .

#### same_digits

Instead of using str, divide (with divmod) both numbers and count digits in a list - adding for a and subtracting for b. If at some point you reach negative value or lengths are different - return `False`. Counting digits is slightly faster than sorting, and you avoid dividing after problem is found.

#### Multiples of 9

The number with this property should be a very specific. The sum of its digits remains the same after multiplication (because digits are the same). If the number is a multiple of 3, the sum of its digits also will be the multiple of 3, the same for 9. But \$3i\$ is a multiple of 3 and has the same digits, so \$i\$ will be the multiple of 3, \$i=3k\$. Once again, \$3i=9k\$ will be the multiple of 9, so i will be the multiple of 9. No sense to check not multiples of 9:

```
for i in count(9,9):
```

#### `6*i` should have the same number of digits

The second idea is that `6*i` should have the same number of digits with i. You can refactor the loop into nested loops: outer for the number of digits (name it `d`) and inner for numbers from 100...08 (`d` digits) to 100..00 (`d+1` digits)/6, everything bigger will make `6*i` have `d+1` digit.

Answer (score 0):

[Pavlo Slavynskyy's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/264139/200133) is excellent!

Depending how concerned you are with performance, the built-in [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class might work for counting digits (or it might be really slow; IDK).

Another small point: The way the `same_digits` function is being used, the digits of `i` are being checked six (or seven) times. That should be avoidable...

You don't strictly need a loop for the task at hand; [next](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) has some gotchas, but should work well here. Taking "no explicit loops" all the way gives us something like

```py
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain, count
from functools import reduce
from more_itertools import pairwise  # or copypast from https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes

def f():
    return next(
        i
        for i
        in chain.from_iterable(range(low, high, 9)
                               for (low, high)
                               in zip((10**d + 8 for d in count(1)),
                                      (10**d // 6 for d in count(2))))
        if all(m1 == m2
               for (m1, m2)
               in pairwise(frozenset(Counter(str(i * m)).items())
                           for m
                           in range(1, 7)))
    )
```

Frankly that could use some more documentation :)